# Wifi keeps dropping

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter

I was running a full install of Ubuntu 21 on my dell i9 without issue and now have recently regularly been having wifi drop. I can cycle the connection and it will reset but drop again at irregular intervals soon thereafter. PITA

I've reinstalled latest 22.04 LTS with no improvement. I've updated, and scoured for answers. Reverting to an elder kernel didn't work.

Ultimately, I'm hoping someone can assist towards a resolution.

Many thanks in advance.

Wireless adapter is:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 01
       serial: 64:d6:9a:62:3b:da
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-41-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf-a0-72.uc ip=192.168.1.37 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:16 memory:6289294000-6289297fff
```

Link to logs per jeremy31 ask.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XP3bDtXjhF/

Ran both Jeremy31's scripts with no positive effect. This is the end of the log. Unsure of the implications.

May  8 10:01:09 Black rtkit-daemon[1301]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May  8 10:01:09 Black rtkit-daemon[1301]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
May  8 10:01:17 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: ScheduleHostLauch called
May  8 10:01:38 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: SchedulePriorTracktype called
May  8 10:01:59 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: ScheduleHostLauch called
May  8 10:02:05 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: ScheduleTimerQuery called
May  8 10:02:11 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: SchedulePriorTracktype called
May  8 10:02:41 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: ScheduleHostLauch called
May  8 10:02:44 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: SchedulePriorTracktype called
May  8 10:03:17 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: SchedulePriorTracktype called
May  8 10:03:23 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: ScheduleHostLauch called
May  8 10:03:38 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: ScheduleTimerQuery called
May  8 10:03:50 Black org.gnome.Nautilus[19857]: SchedulePriorTracktype called

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145907/discussion-on-question-by-user1694586-wifi-keeps-dropping); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I have not. I'll try if you can direct?

Comment: early days but that seems to have worked...thx